# selenium: how to click a page link

Tags: selenium, cucumber

Am using cucumber with selenium-webdriver however, clicking a link on the page doesn't working.

the HTML code:

```
  <li id="menu-item-325" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  menu-item-325">
  <a href="mysite/contact/" class="nav-top-link">Contact</a>
 </li>
```

Test code:

```
const { defineSupportCode } = require('cucumber');
const { Builder, By } = require('selenium-webdriver');

const driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

defineSupportCode(function ({ Given, When, Then }) {
  // Navigation to the url works
  Given('I am on the site homepage', function () {
    return driver.get(url);
  });

  When('When I click Contact', function() {
    return driver.findElement(By.linkText('Contact')).click();
  });
});
```

I also tried:

`return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='mysite/contact/']")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

To click on the link with test as **`Contact`** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page' and starts-with(@id, 'menu-item-')]/a[@class='nav-top-link']")).click();
```

We can get a bit more granular as :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page' and starts-with(@id, 'menu-item-')]/a[@class='nav-top-link' and @href='mysite/contact/']")).click();
```

> Note : **`click()`** method returns **void**

Comment: It doesn't work. how to chain multiple class names? 
`"//li[@class='menu-item menu-item-type-post_type` is this correct !

Comment: @user3462064 Code have no error. You have morphed the actual HTML. Hence doesn't works for you. Show us more of the `outerHTML`.

Comment: With in `li` tag `id="menu-item"` and `class="menu-item"` can't be same.

Comment: Code have no error you must have missed some attribute within the provided HTML or something in the `outerHTML` which you need to show.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes  providing sleep before click works.. try once with waits or Thread.sleep

As normal click does not work and even with sleep, then try

Actions with moveToElement and then click.

You can also try with javascript at final.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use xpaths

Like this one

```
//a[contains(text(),'Contact')]
```

Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Contact')]")).click();
```

OR

```
//a[contains(text(),'Contact') and contains(@class,'nav-top-link')]
```

Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Contact') and contains(@class,'nav-top-link')]
")).click();
```

Also try combination of `xpath` and `javaScriptExecutor`

```
WebElement elemenLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Contact') and contains(@class,'nav-top-link')]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elemenLink );
```